# Securing Apache (WebDav - File upload)

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav

Just a note, I have been a programer for years but always had a real sysadmin to take care of the servers, with my newest job, that is up to me, so this may seem simple, but I'm doing by best to things right. (I know I don't like it ether)

So the question.

I have set up a Apache server and have been Securing it and have read a few places that say I should remove WebDav from Apache (specifically by removing the Apache mod). I is this a good idea, is there any major disadvantages I should know about.

Also I am running a website that is exposed to the net and a admin website that can only be accessed from my local network, is there any way to disallow file upload completely on the web facing site and still have it enabled on the admin site.

Server: Debian, Apache 2.2, PHP.
I error on the side of safety, as long as its not going to be big issue.

Edit: Each site is running on virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the webDav module is not a problem, it's rarely used.  This doesn't affect the normal kind of file uploads that are done by HTTP Post, those will still work fine.

If you want to disable file uploads for one of your virtual hosts, then you can use [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).  Set this to a reasonable size like 5k and the forms on the site will still work,  but files larger than that can't be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was quit helpful. I ended up using `LimitRequestFieldsize` seeing as I am letting a lot of images be uploading by the admin, that with `LimitRequestFields` for the public site get me where I needed to be. Thank you I would have know of these directives without them right next to the link you gave.